# C++ Pre-processor define after class keyword and before class name

Tags: c++, class, c-preprocessor

I recently came across this sort of code in someone's opengl shader class and am not sure of its use.

As I understand it from reading [IBM's documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fdefine.htm), the #define ONEWORD will remove any occurence of ONEWORD in the subsequent text.

What is the purpose of having ONEWORD in this code at all if all occurrences are removed? What does having a token like that, after a class keyword but before a class name, really mean?
I've only used #define for include guards in the past so this is entirely new for me.

```
#define ONEWORD

class ONEWORD FooClass
{
    FooClass();
    ~FooClass();
};
```

The code I saw this in is here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/104992465/glsl.h
Just in case I've made its context too abstract.

Comment: Often I've seen two-legged animals walking into some mysterious square enclosures, what's that all about? [Well, to answer it myself, it is about removing critical information about what I've observed, and generalizing my own impression, and then asking about that.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, so after looking at the **actual** code, it's not `ONEWORD`, but rather `GLSAPI`. These `XYZ_API` macros are often used for conditionally specifying platform-specific linkage, such as some `__attributes__` which require different treatment on, for example, Windows and Unixes. So you can expect `GLSAPI` to be defined in one of the header files (maybe in `config.h`) like this:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#    define GLSAPI __dllimport
#elif defined __linux__
#    define GLSAPI __attribute__((visibility("visible")))
#else
#    define GLSAPI
#endif
```

(Pseudo-code, I'm not sure about all the attributes and linkage "qualifiers", but you can look them up in the code.)

Comment: The #else if line is dubious.

Comment: In the actual code, it wasn't defined like this. There was just the line `#define GLSAPI`

Comment: @maditya I'm not saying how it **was** defined, I was trying to explain how it **tends to be** defined, and what's the reason for that.

Comment: @H2CO3: the actual code appears to be a quick-n-dirty adaption for static linking of the library.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Nice. Nevertheless, I'm still right, aren't I?

Comment: yeah, or it can be defined in the compiler invocation

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Could you explain the static linking thing? I've never seen it before ...

Comment: @madity: that's the comment that's attached to the definition of `GLSAPI` as nothing. presumably for linking as a shared library this symbol is defined as `_declspec( dllexport )` on Windows. so on. google it

Comment: I thought it might be that, but in that case why not define it the way @H2CO3 has done, i.e. wrap the #define with an #ifdef?

Comment: @maditya: i can only speculate, but often in my own work i have found that people tend to do what's least work for themselves and most impractical (up to a limit) for the next guy. not only does that make one able to finish on time, but compared to next guy one looks good. -> promotion follows. ;-)

Comment: Very enlightening replies for this question, I appreciate the responses and am sorry for not proving enough context in the code given. I now know what this pattern was used for and what to look for to learn more about it.

Answer (score 7):

It's to allow you to easily add compiler specific keywords to your class declaration. For instance with Visual Studio, if you wanted to put this class in a DLL, you would change your definition to

```
#define ONEWORD __declspec( dllexport )
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for another example