# What's a macro before a function or a class in C++?

Tags: c++

I've seen some codes like this：

```
#define A // macro
A void foo(bar); // function declaration
```

and this:

```
#define B // macro
class B foo { // class declaration
  bar
};
```

What's the meaning of using a macro there?

Er...I mean I don't understand the grammar. I haven't seen this before.

In fact, I just find this kind of codes in `features2d.hpp` in opencv3.1.

```
class CV_EXPORTS_W BOWImgDescriptorExtractor {
...
CV_WRAP void setVocabulary( const Mat& vocabulary );
...
}
```

In cvdef.h

```
#if (defined WIN32 || defined _WIN32 || defined WINCE || defined __CYGWIN__) && defined CVAPI_EXPORTS
#  define CV_EXPORTS __declspec(dllexport)
#elif defined __GNUC__ && __GNUC__ >= 4
#  define CV_EXPORTS __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#else
#  define CV_EXPORTS
#endif

/* special informative macros for wrapper generators */
#define CV_EXPORTS_W CV_EXPORTS
#define CV_WRAP
```

Here, CV_EXPORTS_W and CV_WRAP are macros. I haven't seen this kind of grammar in C++.

Comment: Maybe some kind of marker? For finding related stuff quickly in the source file?

Comment: Look at the macro definition. Maybe it's used to substitute the correct linkage specification, depending on what is being build.

Comment: Some crap from before templates?

Comment: Can we have concrete example? In may be an annotation, a linking specification, obfuscation, ...

Comment: For Visual Studio a common use of this construct is with a DLL. The macro is defined as `__declspec( dllexport )` when building the  DLL and `__declspec( dllimport )` when not.

Comment: A macro before a function is the same thing as a macro anywhere else: simple textual substitution. To know what it does we need to see the actual macro.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you haven't posted the definition of those macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually such things are a placeholder for compiler or system specific extensions to the language.

For example, if building a program using a windows DLL, to import a symbol the function might be declared

```
__declspec(dllimport) void foo();
```

The problem is that the `__declspec(dllimport)` would typically not work if the code is ported to another system, or built using a compiler that does not support such a non-standard feature.

So, instead, the declaration might be

```
#ifdef _WIN32    /*  or some macros specific to a compiler targeting windows */

#define IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define IMPORT
#endif

IMPORT void foo();
```

There are a number of occasions, with particular compilers, targets (e.g. a program importing a symbol from a library, or a library being built to export a symbol), and host systems where such a technique might be used.

Answer (score 2):

> Er...I mean I don't understand the grammar.

It is a pre-processor macro definition. The first one defines macro by the name `A` and second by the name of `B`. Once those are defined, all occurrences of the identifier `A` and `B` are replaced with an empty string by the preprocessor. It is also possible for the preprocessor to test whether a macro is defined and conditionally produce code, using `#ifdef`.

> What's the meaning of using a macro there?

The name of the macros are not helpful, so it's impossible to tell.

As for `__declspec(dllexport)` see my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34092746/2079303). It is an implementation defined specifier for dynamic linking used in msvc compiler. `__attribute__` is a specifier for implementation defined behaviour in the GNU compiler. The macro is used to select the correct specifier depending on the target compiler.