# What does BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL in class declaration mean?

Tags: c++, class, boost

I found the following code:

```
class BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL path
{

};
```

Usually a class is defined this way:

```
class Baloon 
{

};
```

How can I have two terms in the class declaration? Does somebody knows what `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL` is used for (boost library)?

Comment: `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL` is just a macro for `__declspec(dllimport)` (or nothing, if it's not needed).

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at [how it is defined](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/boost/filesystem/config.hpp), all will be clear:

```
#ifdef BOOST_HAS_DECLSPEC // defined in config system
// we need to import/export our code only if the user has specifically
// asked for it by defining either BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK if they want all boost
// libraries to be dynamically linked, or BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK
// if they want just this one to be dynamically liked:
#if defined(BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK) || defined(BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK)
// export if this is our own source, otherwise import:
#ifdef BOOST_FILESYSTEM_SOURCE
# define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
# define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif  // BOOST_FILESYSTEM_SOURCE
#endif  // DYN_LINK
#endif  // BOOST_HAS_DECLSPEC
//
// if BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL isn't defined yet define it now:
#ifndef BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL
#endif
```

As you can see, it is a macro. It expands to `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` or empty, depending on other macros. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34092746/2079303) for more details about declspec specifier. In short, it is platform specific feature that is needed for dynamic linking.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually a macro that evaluates to either `__declspec(dllimport)` or `__declspec(dllexport)`, and it's basically being used by the Boost libraries to tell the compiler to export (for their own code) or import (for external code).

Answer (score 0):

The *BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL* is probably a [macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html), look for the declaration:

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL
```

to see what it's mean.

Comment: Also, the question wasn't "what this macro does?", the main problem was he didn't understand this is a macro.

Comment: Actually, the end of OP's post is *"Does somebody knows what BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL is used for (boost library)?"*, so yes, he asked for the purpose of this particular macro. IMO, saying `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL` being a macro is not an answer to such question, because knowing that it comes down to `class __declspec(dllimport) path` just push the problem one step further.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I didn't vote down, I think the answer is fine. But  is it a macro, or isn't it? If it isn't, then looking for `#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL ` won't help much. **I** know that it is, but a user who doesn't know that might not appreciate the speculative answer.